# Error: El servidor MySQL no autorizó su acceso

Tags: mysql

he estado tratando de ingresar a phpMyAdmin de forma local, por lo que instale xampp en mi computadora, el problema es que cuando trato de ingresar a phpMyAdmin me salen el error de "El servidor MySQL no autorizó su acceso" aclaro que he cambiado la configuración de "config.inc.php" los valores de password y de auth type, la password a "root" y auth type a "cookie" ingreso esos valores en la interfaz gráfica de phpMyAdmin y sin embargo sigo con el mismo problema, también he cambiado la password de mysql desde la consola con el siguiente comando "update user set password=PASSWORD("root") where user='root';". Agradezco si alguien me puede ayudar.

Adjunto imagen del error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cambia el tipo de autentificación a `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';` y verifica que el usuario y contraseña sean los que especificaste al instalar XAMPP.